# trying to run webpy example: app isn't defined

Tags: python, web.py

I am trying to implement a captcha based on someone elses code using webpy. The code I am starting with is here: https://kzar.co.uk/blog/2009/07/14/web.py-captcha/

The example code there isn't complete, and I need to work out what to do with this app variable. Here is my code:

```
import web
from captcha import getCaptcha

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
        '/([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+)', 'index',
        '/', 'index',
        '/captcha.gif', 'captcha'
        )

if web.config.get("_session") is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'captcha': ''})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

vcaptcha = form.Validator('Please enter the code', lambda x:x == session.captcha)

enquiry_form = form.Form(
        form.Textbox("captcha", vcaptcha, description="Validation Code", pre="<img src='/captcha.gif' valign=center><br>", class_="standard", style="width:70px;"),
        )

class index:
    def GET(self, argu = "Anonymous/Person"):
        args = argu.split('/')
        firstname = args[0]
        if (len(args) >= 2):
            lastname = args[1]
            return render.index(firstname, lastname)
        return render.index(firstname, "Snow")

class captcha:
    def GET(self):
        web.header("Content-Type", "image/gif")
        captcha = getCaptcha
        session.captcha = captcha[0]
        return captcha[1].read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

It gives this error when ran:

```
$ python code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 13, in <module>
    session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'captcha': ''})
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

I've been looking at the webpy documentation and API reference, and I can't figure out what to do to properly initialise this 'app' variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the as yet undefined `app` when you call `session = web.session.Session(app, ...`
Have you seen the documentation on [sessions](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions)? See how they define `app` in the example prior to using it.

Answer (score 1):

Just after URLs one is supposed to have this:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```